# Deselect edit control win32 c++

Tags: c++, winapi

How would I go about deselecting the text in edit control?

After entering the input I want the user to be able to deselect the edit control.
Because even after you click out of it and press a key, it gets entered into the edit.

Here is the code for my edit control:

```
HFONT fontMain = CreateFont(
            -16,                                                // Height Of Font
            0,                                                  // Width Of Font
            0,                                                  // Angle Of Escapement
            0,                                                  // Orientation Angle
            0,      // Font Weight
            false,                              // Italic
            false,                          // Underline
            false,                          // Strikeout
            ANSI_CHARSET,                               // Character Set Identifier
            OUT_TT_PRECIS,                                      // Output Precision
            CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,                                // Clipping Precision
            ANTIALIASED_QUALITY,                                // Output Quality
            FF_DONTCARE|DEFAULT_PITCH,                          // Family And Pitch
            TEXT("Calibri"));

HWND editControl = CreateWindow(
                TEXT("EDIT"),
                TEXT("TEST TEXT"),
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_LEFT | ES_MULTILINE,
                x, y, width, height,
                window,
                (HMENU) 100,
                instance,
                NULL);
SendMessage(window /* parent window */, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)fontMain, NULL);
DeleteObject(fontMain);
```

I have checked MSDN docs and have not found any additional styles to add to achieve the task.

If you have any ideas on how to achieve this task could you help me out?
Thank you.

Comment: [`EM_SETSEL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-setsel) ?

Comment: @PaulSanders Would I implement it as a style or a message?

Comment: In Win32, focus doesn't change when you click out of a focused control, but when you click into another window capable of being focused.

Comment: @PaulSanders: Although the phrase "deselecting the text in edit control" does appear in the question, when reading the entire question I am convinced that OP wants to control focus and not the selected range.

Comment: @BenVoigt I think you're right, _Because even after you click out of it and press a key, it gets entered into the edit._

Comment: @BenVoigt Is there any way I could somehow send a message to the parent window to remove the edit control from focus?

Comment: So, OP, what do you mean please when you say "after you click out of it".  Where, in particular, did you click?  And yes, you can set the focus to another window by calling `SetFocus`.

Comment: @AmritSanjeev: You need to put another window/control into focus, then the edit control will naturally lose focus.

Comment: @PaulSanders When I click on the parent window alone.

Comment: @BenVoigt Could I possibly achieve it by putting the parent window into focus?

Comment: Relevant reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/about-keyboard-input#keyboard-focus-and-activation

Comment: If I'm remembering correctly, it's not possible for a parent window to have focus if it has at least one child window capable of being focused.  But you can certainly call the `SetFocus()` function passing the parent HWND.  **It's also legal to call `SetFocus(NULL)`.**  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setfocus

Comment: _When I click on the parent window alone._  That doesn't normally send the input focus anywhere (it just stays where it is), so why do you want your app to behave differently?

Comment: SetFocus worked for me. I just passed the parent window as the parameter and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the same trick that works to dismiss dropdown list (of combo box), popup menus, and the like.

1. You'll need to subclass the EDIT control so you receive messages first to your own window procedure.
2. In your textbox subclass `WM_SETFOCUS` handler, call `SetCapture` so the next click is delivered to the textbox even if it's outside.
3. In the textbox subclasses's handler for mouse click messages, test the location and if outside the textbox, call `SetFocus(NULL)` to give up the focus.  (This is where a popup would dismiss itself).  Also call `ReleaseCapture()`.
4. Also call `ReleaseCapture()` in the subclass's `WM_KILLFOCUS` handler, since mouse clicks are not the only way to lose focus.

---

The above is the way to have *any click outside the textbox* remove its focus.  If you only want clicks in the client area of your parent window to defocus the textbox, then you can certainly skip the subclassing and capture, and just handle the mouse click events in the parent window, calling `SetFocus(NULL)` or `SetFocus(parentHWnd)`.

Comment: `SetCapture` - a piece of undervalued Windows magic.

Answer (score 0):

I handled the WM_LBUTTONDOWN message in the window proc.

Such that when I click the mouse button on the parent window, it will set the focus to the parent window.

```
static LRESULT WINAPI WndProc
     (HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(message){
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN : {
            // Passing the parent window as the parameter.
            SetFocus(HWND parentWindow);
        }
    }
}
```

This method works as the WM_LBUTTONDOWN might not be triggered if you click on any other window except the parent window.

There might be some exceptions to the above statement, but overall it works with buttons and edits **but not static text** for some reason.

**The answers were provided by:**
**@PaulSanders and @BenVoigt**

Comment: Nothing to do with clicking at all then?

Comment: @PaulSanders: I'm sure he meant to call it from inside a mouse button message handler somewhere.

Comment: This proposed answer is incomplete at best, and certainly not useful. I wonder who felt the urge to upvote it nevertheless.